# Should we edit in links to uncommon names (in this case, a disorder)

Tags: discussion

Question [How to tell my girlfriend, my friends and relatives that I might have alexithymia, without making it sound like an excuse?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/how-to-tell-my-girlfriend-my-friends-and-relatives-that-i-might-have-alexithymi) contains the not very common disorder name of [Alexithymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia).

In general, is it a good idea to edit in an explanatory link (like the above one to Wikipedia)?

Answer (score 12):

This seems to be the kind of thing that the edit functionality was made for. You're not changing the nature of the question in any way, you're just making it clearer and easier to understand.

I think the best way to do this would be to edit in a link along with a summary of the relevant information on the destination page and to leave a comment inviting the OP to check the reference and change it if they prefer another one.

Don't forget that summary, because this is the internet and the destination page may change, whereas we want the questions and answers on Stackexchange to remain relevant without requiring maintenance, so the essential information should remain intact.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, why not?

Make sure to explain your action by leaving a nice edit message and/or comment, maybe something to the extent of

> 'Hey, I never heard of this disorder and had to google it, so I added one of the links I found to your answer for future viewers. If it contains any information that isn't correct or if you have a better/preferred source, feel free to change it.'

I see only 1 in which I would advise against doing so: **If a question is on-hold, and the edit will not be to such an extent that it'll make the question eligible for reopening.** Questions on-hold only get 1 edit that pushes them into the reopen queue, so I would wait until the necessary clarifications are made and then edit all at once.

Also, keep in mind that every edit will send a post to the front page of active posts again, so editing all old posts right now is overkill.